# Call Ask Permissions on UI Thread

Tags: c#, xamarin

When loading the app I am working on it calls

```
await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();
```

to make sure the app has permissions to get the GPS lat, long. When it does this I get the exception

> Permission request must be invoked on main thread

how do I ensure this is done on the UI Thread ?

Answer (score 0):

This should give you everything you need to do this in Xamarin Forms.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.mainthread?view=xamarin-essentials